# How to change name of a table created by AWS Glue crawler using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, boto3, aws-glue-data-catalog

I'm trying to change the table name created by AWS Crawler using boto3. Here is the code:

```py
import boto3

database_name = "eventbus"
table_name = "enrollment_user_enroll_cancel_1_0_0"
new_table_name = "enrollment_user_enroll_cancel"

client = boto3.client("glue", region_name='us-west-1')
response = client.get_table(DatabaseName=database_name, Name=table_name)
table_input = response["Table"]
table_input["Name"] = new_table_name
print(table_input)
print(table_input["Name"])

table_input.pop("CreatedBy")
table_input.pop("CreateTime")
table_input.pop("UpdateTime")
client.create_table(DatabaseName=database_name, TableInput=table_input)
```

Getting the below error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in TableInput: "DatabaseName", must be one of: Name, Description, Owner, LastAccessTime, LastAnalyzedTime, Retention, StorageDescriptor, PartitionKeys, ViewOriginalText, ViewExpandedText, TableType, Parameters
Unknown parameter in TableInput: "IsRegisteredWithLakeFormation", must be one of: Name, Description, Owner, LastAccessTime, LastAnalyzedTime, Retention, StorageDescriptor, PartitionKeys, ViewOriginalText, ViewExpandedText, TableType, Parameters
```

Could you please let me know the resolution for this issue? Thanks!

Comment: I'm able to resolve those parameter issues and changed the crawler name. but existing crawler has partitions attached in it by AWS Crawler. Newly changed crawler name doesn't attached the partitions. How do attach the partitions in the changed crawler? Thanks!

Comment: Two possible remedies for this: **1)** Re-run the Crawler and check the Table Changes column in the Crawler runs section of the console; or **2)** Edit the Crawler, adding a data source that is the Glue Table it writes to.  It will now query the original source data via that Glue Table, not directly.  This should then discover the partitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of `botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError` thrown by `client.create_table`, you need to delete the corresponding items from `table_input` in a similar way as you did with `CreatedBy` etc

```py
...

table_input.pop("DatabaseName")
table_input.pop("IsRegisteredWithLakeFormation")

client.create_table(DatabaseName=database_name, TableInput=table_input)
```

In case your original table had partitions, which want to add to a new table, you need to use similar approach. First you need to retrieve meta information about those partitions with either:

- [`batch_get_partition()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.batch_get_partition)
- [`get_partition()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.get_partition)
- [`get_partitions()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.get_partitions)

**Note:** depending which one you chose, you would need to pass different parameters. There are limitation on how many partitions you can retrieve within a single request. If I remember correctly it is around 200 or so. On top of that, you might need to use [page paginator](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Paginator.GetPartitions) to list all of the available partitions. This is the case when your table has more then 400 partitions.

In general, I would suggest to:

```py
paginator = client.get_paginator('get_partitions')
response = paginator.paginate(
    DatabaseName=database_name,
    TableName=table_name
)

partitions = list()
for page in response:
    for p in page['Partitions']:
        partitions.append(p.copy())

# Here you need to remove "DatabaseName", "TableName", "CreationTime" from 
# every partition
```

Now you are ready add those retrieved partition to a new table with either:

- [`batch_create_partition()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.batch_create_partition)
- [`create_partition()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.create_partition)

I'd suggest to use `batch_create_partition()`, however, it limits on how many partitions can be created at the single request.